# Find elements from collection contains names from string array

Tags: c#, linq

How can I create LINQ expression to find elements from collection contains names from string array?

```
string[] names = ["John", "Hanna", "Bill", "Donald"];
```

I've created expression like below but it is not correct. How can I fix that?

```
result = (x => x.CompanyEmployeeName.Contains(names));
```

Comment: Assuming `x` is an employee, you might have a collection of employees. Can you show us that? Remember, it is important that you provide a [mcve] while asking questions, otherwise we may not be able to help.

Comment: the contains usage has to be reversed: `names.Contains(x.CompanyEmployeeName)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want check if `names` contains `x.CompanyEmployeeName`, you'll want to use:

```
result = something.Where(x => names.Contains(x.CompanyEmployeeName));
```

Comment: Depending on the size of `something` and `names`, you might want to use `Join` instead.

Comment: how is this different from the accpted answers in the suggested duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

let `myCollection` be the collection of a custom class having a property `Name`. you have to get all objects from that collection based on the condition that object's name should be available in the `names` array. Then  You can try this:

```
var filteredItems = myCollection.Where(x=> names.Any(y=>y == x.Name));
```

I have added a working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/My0UEs)

Comment: I think this will not work, since `.Any(..)` expects a *predicate*. The `.Name` is a string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: thank you for correcting me. I have updated my post with a working example as per suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse it. Check if the *names* contains the *employee*

```
var result = db.CompanyEmployee.Where(x => names.Contains(x.CompanyEmployeeName));
```

One other option, which is prefered if the list in context are larger then your sample data, is to use Join

```
var result = db.CompanyEmployee.Join(names, x=> x.CompanyEmployeeName, n => n, (x,n)=> n);
```

Comment: how is this different from the accpted answers in the suggested duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

In your LINQ, you should have a collection first.
Ex: if you have a list: listCompanyEmployee then you can use bellow expression:

```
var result = listCompanyEmployee.Where(x => names.Contains(x.CompanyEmployeeName));
```

Comment: how is this different from the accpted answers in the suggested duplicates? or different from the 2 answers here my [Mel Gerats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110672/5174469) and [Marcus Höglund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110669/5174469)?

Comment: Sorry, I think it 's because we have similar answers at the same time( my internet connection is quite slow).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Exists__1___0___System_Predicate___0__). Example if you want to check if `names` contains `CompanyEmployeeName`:

```
result = something.Where(x => Array.Exists(names, name => name == x.CompanyEmployeeName));
```

and you can use [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_IndexOf__1___0_____0_) like:

```
result = something.Where(x => Array.IndexOf(names, x.CompanyEmployeeName) != -1);
```